# How to get the AIC and BIC of a null generalized linear model in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, glm

In statsmodel, is there a way to extract the AIC and BIC of a null generalized linear model? In the documentation I can only find how to get the null deviance:

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults

Comment: This isn't a programming problem.

Comment: Please provide a code for us

Comment: The loglikelihood value of the constant only null model `llnull` is available, but the models have no method to compute information criteria for the null model.